# Generating random points in a box

Tags: python, random, points, packing

I want to generate random points in a box (a=0.2m, b=0.2m, c=1m). This points should have random distance between each other but minimum distance between two points is should be 0.03m, for this I used `random.choice`. When I run my code it generates random points but distance management is so wrong. Also my float converting approximation is terrible because I don't want to change random values which I generate before but I couldn't find any other solution. I'm open to suggestions.

Images

[graph1](https://ibb.co/MsnRfRJ)
[graph2](https://ibb.co/nzCTGKb)

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# BOX a = 0.2m b=0.2m h=1m
    
save = 0 #for saving 3 different plot.
for k in range(3):
    pointsX = [] #information of x coordinates of points
    pointsY = [] #information of y coordinates of points
    pointsZ = [] #information of z coordinates of points
    for i in range(100): #number of the points
        a = random.uniform(0.0,0.00001) #for the numbers generated below are float. 
        
        x = random.choice(range(3, 21,3)) #random coordinates for x
        x1 = x/100 + a
        pointsX.append(x1)
        
        y = random.choice(range(3, 21,3)) #random coordinates for y
        y1 = y/100 + a
        pointsY.append(y1)
        
        z = random.choice(range(3, 98,3)) #random coordinates for z
        z1 = z/100 + a
        pointsZ.append(z1)
        
    new_pointsX = list(set(pointsX)) # deleting if there is a duplicates
    new_pointsY = list(set(pointsY))
    new_pointsZ = list(set(pointsZ))
    
    # i wonder max and min values it is or not between borders.
    print("X-Min", min(new_pointsX)) 
    print("X-Max", max(new_pointsX))
    print("Y-Min", min(new_pointsY))
    print("Y-Max", max(new_pointsY))
    print("Z-Min", min(new_pointsZ))
    print("Z-Max", max(new_pointsZ))
    if max(new_pointsX) >= 0.2 or max(new_pointsY) >= 0.2:
        print("MAX VALUE GREATER THAN 0.2") 
    if max(new_pointsZ) >= 0.97:
        print("MAX VALUE GREATER THAN 0.97")
    
    #3D graph  
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,9))
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.set_xlim([0, 0.2])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 0.2])
    ax.set_zlim([0, 1])
    ax.set_title('title',fontsize=18)
    ax.set_xlabel('X',fontsize=14)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontsize=14)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z',fontsize=14)
    ax.scatter3D(new_pointsX, new_pointsY, new_pointsZ);
    
    save += 1
    plt.savefig("graph" + str(save) + ".png", dpi=900)
```

Comment: I did not get your idea. Why obvious approach can not be used?
Generate random point (x,y,z). Check the distance from previously generated points. If it is too close to one of them, ignore it and cycle again until you will have enough random points. This is not the most effective approach, but it is simple and it will do the job

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [@user3431635](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431635/user3431635), you can check each point with all previous points before appending that new point to the list. I would do that something like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

a = 0.2         # x bound
b = 0.2         # y bound
c = 1.0         # z bound
N = 1000        # number of points

def distance(p, points, min_distance):
    """
    Determines if any points in the list are less than the minimum specified 
    distance apart.

    Parameters
    ----------
    p : tuple
        `(x,y,z)` point.
    points : ndarray
        Array of points to check against. `x, y, z` points are columnwise.
    min_distance : float
        Minimum allowable distance between any two points.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        True if point `p` is at least `min_distance` from all points in `points`.

    """
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((p+points)**2, axis=1))
    distances = np.where(distances < min_distance)
    return distances[0].size < 1

points = np.array([])       # x, y, z columnwise
while points.shape[0] < 1000:
    x = random.choice(np.linspace(0, a, 100000))
    y = random.choice(np.linspace(0, b, 100000))
    z = random.choice(np.linspace(0, c, 100000))
    p = (x,y,z)
    if len(points) == 0:                # add first point blindly
        points = np.array([p])
    elif distance(p, points, 0.03):     # ensure the minimum distance is met
        points = np.vstack((points, p))
        
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,9))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([0, a])
ax.set_ylim([0, b])
ax.set_zlim([0, c])
ax.set_title('title',fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel('X',fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontsize=14)
ax.set_zlabel('Z',fontsize=14)
ax.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], points[:,2])
```

Note, this might not be the randomness you're looking for. I have written it to take the range of x, y, and z values and split it into 100000 increments; a new x, y, or z point is then chosen from those values.